# socket.io prevent one browser generated event it's sending data to all another browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, socket.io

I 'm using socket.io for sending data to an iframe with is cross-domain, everything is working fine, but my issue is

1. when I 'm working in a single browser its working fine but if I open multiple browsers any event generated by one browser it'
   s sending data to all another browser.
2. inside index page there are multiple iframes
3. from index im sending data to iframe
   if it 's in the viewport
4. is there any way to make the differentiation between browsers.

apology my English is not so good

Comment: Please do not include links to GitHub projects in your question. Find the relevant portion of your code and share it directly inline with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('event', data);
```

Comment: where have to use it, server or client

Comment: You need to set up your server so that it is communicating directly to your specific clients in scenarios when you want them. The io.sockets line is on the server side.